# Parse date from EditText to Calendar and calculate age from that

Tags: java, android

I know many people asked this, but I can't seem to get it to work.
I am trying to get the string from editTextBirth and parse it to date and calculate the user's age from that, casting the result onto editTextAge (I want to keep it as EditText, not TextView for personal reasons).

Here's what I got so far:

```
public class AddPatientActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener{

private static final int DATE_DIALOG_ID = R.layout.birthdaypicker;
private EditText editTextName;
private EditText editTextBirth;
private EditText editTextAge;
private EditText editTextComp;
private SimpleDateFormat dateFormat;
private Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
private Calendar now = Calendar.getInstance();
private Button buttonCalc;



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_add_patient);

    editTextName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextName);
    editTextAge = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextAge);
    editTextBirth = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextBirth);
    editTextComp = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextComp);
    buttonCalc = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonCalc);

    dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");


}

@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    //if calc button is pressed
    if (view == buttonCalc) {
        String date = editTextBirth.getText().toString();
        try {
            c.setTime(dateFormat.parse(date));
            int age = now.get(Calendar.YEAR) - c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
            if (now.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR) < c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR)) {
                age--;
            }
            String idade = Integer.toString(age);
            editTextAge.setText(idade);
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

Unfortunately, nothing happens when I click buttonCalc or change the format of the input from ddMMyyyy (how editTextBirth displays it) to dd/MM/yyyy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You created the onClick event but never explicitly assigned it to the button.

Add this snippet below your button declaration:

```
buttonCalc.setOnClickListener(this);
```

@Pavneet_Singh is also correct. You need to compare the view id rather than just the button.

This is what your final soulution should look like:

```
public class AddPatientActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener{


private static final int DATE_DIALOG_ID = R.layout.birthdaypicker;
private EditText editTextName;
private EditText editTextBirth;
private EditText editTextAge;
private EditText editTextComp;
private SimpleDateFormat dateFormat;
private Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
private Calendar now = Calendar.getInstance();
private Button buttonCalc;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_add_patient);

    editTextName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextName);
    editTextAge = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextAge);
    editTextBirth = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextBirth);
    editTextComp = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextComp);
    buttonCalc = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonCalc);
    buttonCalc.setOnClickListener(this);
    dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");


}

@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    //if calc button is pressed
    if (view.getId() == R.id.buttonCalc) {
        String date = editTextBirth.getText().toString();
        try {
            c.setTime(dateFormat.parse(date));
            int age = now.get(Calendar.YEAR) - c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
            if (now.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR) < c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR)) {
                age--;
            }
            String idade = Integer.toString(age);
            editTextAge.setText(idade);
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

}